# Shell script to send an alert mail if disk usage exceeds 90%

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, disk-usage

I want to implement a script on my server which will automatically send email alerts if the disk usage goes over 90% and second email alert when it goes over 95%. My filesystem is `abc:/xyz/abc` and the mount point is `/pqr`.

I have tried this:

```
ADMIN="someone@def.com" 
ALERT=90 
df -H | grep -vE 'abc:/xyz/pqr | tmpfs |cdrom' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }' | while read output; do 
  usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1 ) 
  partition=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $2 }' ) 
    if [ $usep -ge $ALERT ]; then 
      mail -s "Alert: Almost out of disk space $usep" $ADMIN 
    fi 
  done
```

But I am getting an error which says

```
line 7: [: Use: integer expression expected
```

Answer (score 13):

The error is due to one of the arguments to `-ge` not being numeric. Since `$ALERT` is always numeric, `$usep` has to be the culprit. There are several problems with the way you parse the output of `dh` which result in `$usep` not being numeric.

Depending on the lengths of the filesystems, `dh` may split its output on several lines. Partial lines will be caught in your filter and result in nonsensical data. To avoid this behavior and get parseable output from `dh`, pass the `-P` option.

Also `df` prints a header line which again will result in nonsensical data.

Your filter is pretty complex. I would use a single pass of awk. For that matter, you could do the filtering on the percentage inside awk (but I haven't done it in the following script).

```
df -H | awk '
    NR == 1 {next}
    $1 == "abc:/xyz/pqr" {next}
    $1 == "tmpfs" {next}
    $1 == "/dev/cdrom" {next}
    1 {sub(/%/,"",$5); print $1, $5}
' | while read filesystem percentage; do
    if [ "$percentage" -ge "$ALERT" ]; then 
      mail -s "Alert: Almost out of disk space ($usep%) on $filesystem" "$ADMIN"
    fi 
  done
```

`NR==1` matches the first line, so `NR==1 {next}` skips the first line. The next few lines exclude some filesystems (note that your description says that you're interested in `abc:/xyz/pqr`, but your code excludes it). The last awk line removes the `%` from the percentage column before printing it.

It would be nicer to send a single mail about all filesystems. This time I'm doing all the analysis in awk.

```
message=$(df -h | awk -v ALERT="$ALERT" '
    NR == 1 {next}
    $1 == "abc:/xyz/pqr" {next}
    $1 == "tmpfs" {next}
    $1 == "/dev/cdrom" {next}
    1 {sub(/%/,"",$5)}
    $5 >= ALERT {printf "%s is almost full: %d%%\n", $1, $5}
')
if [ -n "$message" ]; then
  echo "$message" | mail -s "Alert: Almost out of disk space" "$ADMIN"
fi
```

Answer (score 6):

If you change print to printf using %d, the percentage will become an integer. Try:

```
printf("%d", $5);
```

which will convert 91% to 91.  So final command is this:

```
df -H | grep /dev/xvde1 | awk '{ printf "%d", $5}'
```

**The above command in english:**  "Get the disk space usage in human readable format.  Filter down with grep to the disk we want to look at.  Pipe that line to awk and print the 5th word delimited by space (empties removed), and format the resulting string as an integer.  For me the command returns the integer `78` which means the disk is 78% full.

Answer (score 4):

```
$ df | tail +2 | sed s/%//g | awk '{ if($5 > 90) print "Alert "$0;}'
```

- `df | tail +2` takes all the output after skipping the first 2 lines
- `sed s/%//g` strips percent signs
- `awk ...` prints "Alert ..."if the 5th field in the output is a number greater than 90

Comment: Welcome to Stack Exchange!  We’re looking for long answers that provide some explanation and context.  Don’t just give a one-line answer; explain how it works.  Answers that don’t include explanations may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

here's my variant:

```
#!/bin/bash

ADMIN=yermail@yerdom.com
ALERT=90
df -H | grep -vE 'abc:/xyz/pqr | tmpfs |cdrom|Used' | awk '{ print $5 " " $1 }' | while read output; do 
usep=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $1}' | cut -d'%' -f1 ) 
echo $usep
partition=$(echo $output | awk '{ print $2 }' ) 
if [ $usep -ge $ALERT ]; then 
  echo  "Alert: Almost out of disk space $usep" 
  df -H | mail -s "Alert: out of disk space $usep"  $ADMIN
fi 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to comment on Gilles answer above, but just be aware that awk is doing a string-based compare in the second part, where:

```
$5 >= ALERT
```

I noticed this when I was testing single-digit thresholds. You can force a cast to int by using +0, so the comparison becomes:

```
$5+0 >= ALERT
```

Answer (score 0):

Done by using awk command

```
df -Ph $f |awk 'NR >1{gsub("%","",$0);print }'| awk -v subject="$subject" '{if($(NF-1)>90){print "mailx -s out of space in "$NF  " praveenkumar.pearl@gmail.com |sh"} else{print "No disk space issu exsists"}}'| sed "s/out/'out/g" |sed "s/.* /&'  /g"
```